# Call action from another action or another view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller called `DappAccount`, in it, I have the action `AccountMainPage` that receives `class` as a parameter. In there I perform login and create the returned model, right into the `AccountMainPage` and `Layout` views.

In the Layout, I have a link (`a` tag) that I want to call back to the `AccountMainPage` action, but I have no idea how to send back the Model.

Here is what I tried:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AccountMainPage(DappAccount account) // here the login succeeded 
{ 
    bool IsValidated = account.CheckLogin(account.publicKey, account.privateKey);  
    if (!IsValidated)
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");

    account.ConnectToBlockchain();

    // save this account in static controller property so the other controllers can read it
    myAccount = account;

    myAccount.OwnAssetsList = 
        await _context.Assets
            .FromSqlRaw("select * from Assets where OwnerPublicKey = {0}", account.publicKey)
            .ToListAsync();

    return View(account);
}
```

And the link element, I think it is failing because it doesn`t send back the model:

```
<a id="assetsNavBar" class="nav-link" 
   asp-area="" asp-controller="DappAccount" asp-action="AccountMainPage">
    Assets<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
</a>
```

I also tried:

```
<a id="assetsNavBar" class="nav-link" 
   asp-area="" asp-controller="DappAccount" asp-action="ShowAssetPage">
    Assets<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
</a>
```

I successfully called the `ShowAssetPage()`, but the redirect fails too:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ShowAssetPage()
{
    return RedirectToAction("AccountMainPage", myAccount); // here the view didn`t load too
}
```

How can I successfully call the `AccountMainPage`?

Comment: I can overcome the problem by duplicate code, but his is no what I want

Comment: I think, you can not send object with anchor tag, yes you can send object but property will not be filled using asp-route-{your action method argument name}="@Model".  You can use form and bind with model and create post or get request then you will have the object in action method.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Xing Zou:

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AccountMainPage(DappAccount account) //here the login succeeded , e initialized the key
{ 
    // so now call again to the login method in order to load more properties 
    bool IsValidated = account.CheckLogin(account.publicKey, account.privateKey); 
    if (!IsValidated)
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");

    account.ConnectToBlockchain();

    // and save this account in static account so the other controllers be able to read it
    myAccount = account;

    myAccount.OwnAssetsList = await _context.Assets.FromSqlRaw("select * from Assets where OwnerPublicKey = {0}", account.publicKey).ToListAsync();

    return View(account);
}
```

And in the Layout view, thanks to @user12376840:

```
<a id="assetsNavBar" class="nav-link" 
   asp-area="" asp-controller="DappAccount" asp-action="AccountMainPage" 
   asp-route-account.publicKey="@Model.publicKey" 
   asp-route-account.privateKey="@Model.privateKey">
    Assets<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass parameter in your AccountMainPage action as route, so try something like this..

```
   <a id="assetsNavBar" class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="DappAccount" asp-action="AccountMainPage" asp-route-account="@new DappAccount(){}">Assets<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

make sure you add the fields within the {} or pass an already accessible DappAccount object

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you are trying to use `<a>` to redirect to a `POST` action. However, both the anchor tag and redirect send `GET` request.

You need to add a `GET` action in `DappAccount` controller to return `AccountMainPage` view

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AccountMainPage() 
{
   var account = ...;
   //get your account 
   return View(account)
}
```

Comment: And what with the [HttpPost]?

Comment: @חיים חדד What do you mean?You could not redirect to a Post action.And could you be more clearly about `doesn`t send back the mode` in your question, what is the model and where you want to send back to?

Comment: The Model is DappAccount, in the controller I have [HttpPost] from the beginning, in order to pass data from the Login view, I added now also [HttpGet] for the link, as you suggested, and it works, but the action doesn't get the parameters. Working on that right now.

Comment: Anyway I solved the problem thank to you and to @user12376840

Comment: @חיים חדד Oh,That' great!